# Humble Bundle Game 'Trine' not working

Tags: 10.10, games

I downloaded the game [Trine](http://trine-thegame.com/site/) from the [Humble frozenbyte Bundle](http://humblebundle.com) and installed it on Ubuntu 10.10 but for some reason it fails to launch.

I downloaded the `Trine.32.run` file and made it executable and then double clicked it and a installation dialogue opened and the game seemed to install properly, I got game launcher on Desktop and Application Menu but when I click on the game launcher, a [window opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQnf6.png) and when I click on `Launch` Nothing happens.

Here is the error I get when I lanch it from command line by going into the installation directory...

```
gaurav@gaurav-HCL-ME-Laptop:~/trine$ ./trine-launcher32 
./trine-launcher32: ./lib32/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libglade-2.0.so.0)
Got signal 11 at (nil) from (nil)
./trine-bin32[0x8078188]
[0x7e040c]
Aborted
```

This very same issue occurs on two of my computers.

**UPDATE :**

Now when I launch the game a message pops up saying

> Error compiling shaders. Make sure
>   your GPU supports Shader Model 3.0.
>   Additional details may be found in the
>   log.

Here is what game log in `~/.frozenbyte/trine/logs/log.txt` states...

```
14.1.2010 [2:01]
INFO: Vertex profile: arbvp1
INFO: Vertex shader options:
INFO: NumTemps=32
INFO: MaxInstructions=4096
INFO: MaxAddressRegs=1
INFO: MaxLocalParams=1024
INFO: Pixel profile: arbfp1
INFO: Pixel shader options:
INFO: ARB_draw_buffers
INFO: NumTemps=256
INFO: NumInstructionSlots=16384
INFO: NumTexInstructionSlots=16384
INFO: NumMathInstructionSlots=16384
INFO: MaxTexIndirections=16384
INFO: MaxLocalParams=1024
INFO: MaxDrawBuffers=4
ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)

ERROR: Cg error: 4 4 (The program could not load.)
```

PS: I contacted the Humble Bundle support but they didn't have any clue about the issue, so my only hope is to get some help from ubuntu community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Trine forums - http://frozenbyte.com/board/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=3312&sid=b4af10cefb1966b58753b4e7613dea88

I have the same problem but after turning all options off and graphics to lowest it shows the error that aborts the game. "Fatal error: Error compiling shaders. Make sure your GPU supports Shader Model 3.0. Additional details may be found in the log.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem.. I guess our libglade-2.0.so.0 doesn't like the libxml2.so.2 that was provided by Frozenbyte :S

```
~/trine $ ./trine-launcher  
./trine-launcher32: ./lib32/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libglade-2.0.so.0)
Segmentation fault
```

What I think is happening is that libglade (libglade-2.6.4 on my gentoo x86 system) gives a warning about a possibly incompatible libxml2, still proceeds and then segfaults. For me it doesn't even open the launcher, but the game itself works using ./trine-bin .

My very limited knowledge assumes that we either need a newer libxml2 from Frozenbyte (I tried using libxml2-2.7.8 from my system, but this just gives a segfault without any warning) or fix our own systems with a different (patched? older?) libglade.. Now I depend on an expert :P

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility that I encountered is that you've run the application installer using sudo, and had selected the start application now option - creating a .frozenbyte directory that is owned by root, and will prevent the application from saving its settings when you run it as a regular user.

Comment: I have done all the process without using sudo or root account and the game is installed inside my Home folder, so there's no chance of a root permission error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with the frozenbyte games (very slow reaction from control input and graphic glitches all the time). Playing them in windowed mode (even with high resolution) solved almost every problem. I'm on ubuntu 10.10 with an ATI 560v (mobile graphics card) and the fglrx drivers.

I'm also using the gnome-shell desktop so that might be messing things up a little, too.